# Tesseract couldn't load any languages (node tesseract.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tesseract, tesseract.js

I ran `npm install tesseract.js` and now I try to run this code:

```js
const Tesseract = require('tesseract.js');

const filename = 'Screen Shot 2018-01-13 at 16.51.06.png';

Tesseract.recognize(filename)
.progress(p => {
  console.log('progress', p)
}).catch(err =>
  console.error(err)
).then(result => {
  console.log(result.text);
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Really simple, `Screen Shot 2018-01-13 at 16.51.06.png` is an image of text in the same directory.

This code outputs:

```
progress { status: 'loading tesseract core' }
progress { status: 'loaded tesseract core' }
progress { status: 'initializing tesseract', progress: 0 }
pre-main prep time: 54 ms
progress { status: 'initializing tesseract', progress: 1 }
progress { status: 'loading eng.traineddata', progress: 0 }
progress { status: 'loading eng.traineddata', progress: 1 }
progress { status: 'initializing api', progress: 0 }
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
progress { status: 'initializing api', progress: 0.3 }
progress { status: 'initializing api', progress: 0.6 }
progress { status: 'initializing api', progress: 1 }
progress { status: 'recognizing text', progress: 0 }
AdaptedTemplates != NULL:Error:Assert failed:in file ../classify/adaptmatch.cpp, line 190

./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:4
function f(a){throw a;}var h=void 0,i=!0,j=null,k=!1;function aa(){return function(){}}function ba(a){return function(){return a}}var n,Module;Module||(Module=eval("(function() { try { return TesseractCore || {} } catch(e) { return {} } })()"));var ca={},da;for(da in Module)Module.hasOwnProperty(da)&&(ca[da]=Module[da]);var ea=i,fa=!ea&&i;
              ^
abort() at Error
    at Na (./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:32:26)
    at Object.ka [as abort] (./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:507:108)
    at _abort (./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:373:173)
    at $L (./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:383:55709)
    at jpa (./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:388:22274)
    at lT (./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:387:80568)
    at mT (./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:387:80700)
    at Array.BS (./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:387:69011)
    at bP (./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:383:110121)
    at jT (./node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:387:80280)
If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can give more information.
```

---

For comparison here's the regular tesseract command (installed with home-brew):

```
$ tesseract 'Screen Shot 2018-01-13 at 16.51.06.png' stdout
Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Do you like anyone?

Um, I have a bf

Delivered

Ohh haha
```

---

How can I get tesseract.js working?

Comment: Hum.. maybe a locla path problem, I am trying to use it too :)

https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/130

Comment: Ok, found the solution here:

https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/136

Comment: @nodeover [mcstoronto's solution](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/136#issuecomment-318857829) in that issue worked for me. I'll wait a day if you want to post an answer in that time, then I'll add one myself. Thanks for finding that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [GitHub](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/136#issuecomment-318857829):

> I was able to get this working by downloading the trained language data for the language I need from [here](https://github.com/naptha/tessdata/tree/gh-pages/3.02). Unzip the file and put it somewhere in your solution. Then the call to Tesseract will look something like the below. You probably want to save a reference to what is returned by create because loading the file takes some time.
>
> ```
> var tesseractPromise = tesseract.create({ langPath: "eng.traineddata" }).recognize(imagePath, 'eng');
> ```

`eng.traineddata` *has* to go into the root folder, or same directory as the calling node script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete **eng.traineddata** from the root directory of your application and restart the application.